# Derivative of this equation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

I want to ask something. My friend asked me to help to check if the derivative of equation 9 is shown by equation 10. I don't really how to solve it manually so I tried to check from Mathematica, but the result is different. Can you help me to check and explain if the derivative in equation 10 is actually correct?
[image]

```
f[\[Theta]_] := 
 w (Log[\[Theta]]/Log[2])^2 + (2 K V t^(Log[\[Theta]]/Log[2]))/(2 - p)
f'[\[Theta]]
```

[image]

Comment: Be careful, once again. `KVt` is in blue color. This means it is not defined. It is not defined because you forgot to put spaces in between.

Comment: I try to put spaces between K V t but the result is still different from the equation 10. Here is the result : https://ibb.co/rt4zKRp
Is there anything i should check again from my syntax? Or the result given is actually just the same with equation 10? @Domen

Comment: Maximum is obtained at $f'(θ)=0$. Therefore, you have to do `Solve[f'[\[Theta]==0, \[Theta]]`.

Answer (score 1):

You found the derivative of `f` correctly. But the expression for $\theta^*$ in the paper is for the value of $\theta$ which extremizes $f$, which is found by setting $f'(\theta)$ to zero and solving for $\theta$:

```
Solve[f'[\[Theta]] == 0, \[Theta]]

(* {{\[Theta] -> 2^(-(ProductLog[-((K V Log[t]^2)/((-2 + p) w))]/Log[t]))}} *)
```

This can be seen to be equivalent to the paper's expression if you take into account the following two facts:

- [`ProductLog` is the Mathematica implementation of the Lambert W-function.](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html)
- $2^x = e^{x \ln 2}.$

Comment: This is not any maximum in view of `f[p_, w_, K_, V_, t_] := 
 Maximize[{w (Log[\[Theta]]/  Log[2])^2 + (2 K V t^(Log[\[Theta]]/Log[2]))/(2 -   p), \[Theta] > 0}, \[Theta]]` and `f[1, 1, 2, 3, 1/2]` which results in `{\[Infinity], {\[Theta] -> 0}}` with a warning "Maximize::natt: The maximum is not attained at any point satisfying the given constraints.".

Comment: @user64494:  Thanks for the catch.  It is in fact a minimum — and in the OP's context that makes sense, since $f$ is a cost function.  Corrected.